# In Postfix, how do I block all clients whose reverse DNS is in a domain?

Tags: postfix, spam

I just got hit by a spammer sending spam through my mail server from multiple IP addresses in various netblocks all with a reverse lookup ending in `googleusercontent.com`. (I haven't figured out how; my server kept replying "reject" to some while letting others through.) I'd like to block all IP addresses in the domain. I have this in my `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
        check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient
        permit_sasl_authenticated
        reject_unauth_destination
        check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_override
        check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/domains
        reject_rbl_client <several lines like this for blocklists>
```

`rbl_override` has several IP addresses (some with only three numbers, i.e. a netblock) followed by `OK` or `REJECT`. Does it make sense to put `googleusercontent.com` in `rbl_override`? Is there a way to block all IP addresses whose reverse DNS is in this domain?

(`reject_unauth_destination` was after the RBLs while the spam was getting through.)

Comment: AFAIK You can use a postfix [`access` map](https://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) to apply access controls and for example block all hosts in a particular domain. in `/etc/postfix/access`  add for example `googleusercontent.com REJECT`

Comment: I don't have `/etc/postfix/access`. What do I put in `main.cf`?

Comment: The manual page includes a EXAMPLE chapter with instructions on how to implement that.

Comment: There is a difference between a) refusing senders that cannot be bothered to change their reverse association from what their provider has setup as a verbose default, or b) refusing any sender using the services of that provider, including those having configured a custom name. Which do you want?

Comment: Which of the many Postfix manual pages?

Comment: All the IP addresses that sent spam that I found in deferred had `googleusercontent.com` in their reverse lookup. Blocking everything with that reverse lookup should be sufficient. I think I'll do this temporarily and remove the block if I hear back from Google that they've removed the account or fixed the security hole or whatever.

Comment: I added `googleusercontent.com REJECT` to `rbl_override` and am waiting to see what happens if another connect attempt comes from there.